# A clean system for github pages with local plugins

Tags: git, github

Since github doesn't execute (the `safe` option for jekyll) plugins, I am trying to develop a small and clean way to deploy the compiled files to the branch `master`.

The usual source is in the branch `boilerplate`, from there I run jekyll and generate the code, everything works.

In the master branch I only have the following `Makefile`

```
default:
    git checkout boilerplate
    git subtree split -P _site -b site
    git checkout master
    git merge -X theirs site
    git branch -D site
```

and the file `.nojekyll` (I'm using the subtree command from [here](https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree/blob/master/git-subtree.txt))

However this does not work. It generates the `site` branch with all the code, but when I merge into `master`, all it says is:

> Already up-to-date.

How to fix this?

What I want to accomplish is to overwrite any existing files in `master` BUT not delete the files which don't exist in branch `site` (like the aforementioned `Makefile` and `.nojekyll`, which is important to be kept there).

*Note*: I want to do it from scratch in order to maintain control over the deployment process. I don't want to 1. introduce new dependencies 2. use other tools.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As I told on IRC I'd go with a git hook (`git help hooks`)

I hacked [`this`](https://gist.github.com/1002667) script real quick. 
Place it under `$GIT_DIR/.git/hooks/`.

I tested it as a *post-commit* hook commiting from `$_origbranch` and checked the results on the other branch (`$_destbranch`).

It should kind-of do what you want. Worked fine, so I hope it fits you or steers this into somewhat right direction.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# executables prefix
_prefix="/usr/bin"
# git executable
_git="$_prefix/git"

# site generation executable
_generate="$_prefix/jekyll"
# options for the generator
_opts=(--no-safe --no-server --no-auto --kramdown)

# branch from which to generate site
_origbranch="master"
# branch holding the generated site
_destbranch="gh-pages"

# directory holding the generated site -- should be outside this repo
_site="$("$_prefix/mktemp" -d /tmp/_site.XXXXXXXXX)"
# the current branch
_currbranch="$(/bin/grep "^*" < <("$_git" branch) | /bin/cut -d' ' -f2)"

if [[ $_currbranch == $_origbranch ]]; then # we should generate the site
    # go to root dir of the repo
    cd "$("$_git" rev-parse --show-toplevel)"
    # generate the site
    "$_generate" ${_opts[@]} . "$_site"
    # switch to branch the site will be stored
    "$_git" checkout "$_destbranch"
    # overwrite existing files
    builtin shopt -s dotglob
    /bin/cp -rf "$_site"/* .
    builtin shopt -u dotglob
    # add any new files
    "$_git" add .
    # commit all changes with a default message
    "$_git" commit -a -m "updated site @ $(date +"%F %T")"
    # cleanup
    /bin/rm -rfv "$_site"
    # return
    "$_git" checkout "$_origbranch"
fi
```

have fun o/

---

Just an update to say this works with bash and Linux. 
It can probably be written in POSIX sh too. 
Also, I believe mktemp is GNU-coreutils only, so other systems may need to replace this.

NOTE: this only runs when you commit in the branch specified by `$_origbranch`. You can ofcourse change that. I believe it's simple enough for anyone to do that.